# How to convert mins : secs into seconds in Python pandas data?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a football game dataset using python panda data. Now I have a column which is called 'gameClock', it has 'minutes : seconds' formation, like 7:52, 13:31, etc. I am trying to convert this format into seconds left for each quarter. For example, 7:52 means there is 7:08 time left for this quarter, it is equivalent to 428 seconds left for this quarter. But I have no idea how to convert these minutes:seconds time formation into all seconds left for the 900 seconds quarter. I tried the '.split()', but it returns an error like ''Series' object has no attribute 'split''. Please help me out with it. Thanks.

Comment: Try `.str.split()` instead.

Comment: Hello Michael, I tried .str.split(':') , it returns a pd.series like [7,52] [13,31] ... So how can I convert this series into seconds?

Comment: `7:52` to 900s is `7:08` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), then get the [`total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html) and [`rsub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rsub.html) to 900:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'gameClock': ['7:52', '13:31']})

df['out'] = (pd.to_timedelta('00:'+df['gameClock'])
             .dt.total_seconds().rsub(900)
             .convert_dtypes()
             )
```

Alternatively:

```
df['out'] = (pd.to_timedelta('00:'+df['gameClock'])
             .rsub(pd.Timedelta('900s'))
             .dt.total_seconds()
             .convert_dtypes()
             )
```

Output:

```
  gameClock  out
0      7:52  428
1     13:31   89
```

If you want to convert to seconds manually:

```
df['seconds'] = (df['gameClock']
                 .str.split(':', expand=True)
                 .astype(int)
                 .mul([60,1])
                 .sum(axis=1)
                 )
```

Output:

```
  gameClock  seconds
0      7:52      472
1     13:31      811
```

Comment: Hi Mozway, I have a question about this, so .rsub() is to subtract the value from the items, as the example, 7:52 after dt.total_seconds(), it should turned to 472 seconds, and then .rsub(900) will yield 472-900 = -428 seconds. So, which code turns this negative sign out and turn it into a positive value of 428 seconds?